# Delisting the app from AppExchange but keeping LMA features

Tags: appexchange, lma

We have a package which will be delisted from AppExchange for a number of reasons (our decision). I would like to know if any one has similar experience and would this process influence the LMA Login to subscriber orgs feature.

Thanks!